# Reverse proxy websocket IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, websocket, webserver, reverse-proxy

I would like to use IIS to proxy websocket on windows. So, I set up IIS 8 in Winserver 2012, for reverse proxying a websocket server app. But I don't know how to configure IIS. There is just redirect rules for HTTP and HTTPS, no WS. I would like to have the same thing as apache :

```
<Location /ws>
ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8080 
ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>
```

The request ws://127.0.0.1:80/ws will be redirect to ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anybody who had configured this situation ? I am searching the hole web! Everywhere there is a comment 'yes it is possible', but nowhere to find an example!

Comment: I have not found the answer yet. No example on the Microsoft IIS web site...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Use the following code in your web.config:
    `<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="WS reverse proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="ws://127.0.0.1" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://127.0.0.1:8080" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>`

Do not forget to enable WebSocket in IIS.